# Operations on dataframe rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 10], [2, 15], [3, 14], [4, 15], [5, 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'lastprice'])
```

1. I want to take onelastprice and multiply it by 2 (say, x = 2* lastprice)
2. Add lastprice of row above and below row. (say, y = lastprice[-1]+ lastprice[1])
3. add x/y to new column (say "New")
4. repeat it for every row (for any value not available, considered as zero).
5. print max 3 values of "New" with their other row values

How to do this in most efficient way?

Comment: If you include your expected output based on the given input, and show what you've tried so far, it would make it clearer what specifically you need help with

Comment: "Add lastprice of row above and below row" sounds like pandas `rolling()` or `shift()`

Comment: I dont know how to roll out values for above and below row. Thats why stucked.

Comment: okay i will check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = df["lastprice"] * 2

y = df["lastprice"].shift(1, fill_value=0) + df["lastprice"].shift(-1, fill_value=0)

df["new"] = x / y
```

Does it what you expect? (I don't understand 5)

```
>>> df
   Name  lastprice       new
0     1         10  1.333333
1     2         15  1.250000
2     3         14  0.933333
3     4         15  1.071429
4     5         14  1.866667
```

To avoid loop, you can shift your values:

```
df["lastprice[-1]"] = df["lastprice"].shift(1)  # values shifted to the bottom

df["lastprice[1]"] = df["lastprice"].shift(-1)  # values shifted to the top
```

```
>>> df
   Name  lastprice  lastprice[-1]  lastprice[1]
0     1         10            NaN          15.0
1     2         15           10.0          14.0
2     3         14           15.0          15.0
3     4         15           14.0          14.0
4     5         14           15.0           NaN
```

Comment: Nice solution! Can we use `df['new'] = df["lastprice"] * 2 / (df["lastprice"].shift(1, fill_value=0) + df["lastprice"].shift(-1, fill_value=0))` ?

Comment: Yes you can, variables `x` and `y` are intermediate variables and they are not mandatories

Comment: Thanks! I'm learning `.shift()` to avoid `for-loop` :-)

Answer (score 1):

The use of `df.loc[row, col]` can be used for a wide range of manipulation. Although this might not be the most efficient way, but it gets the job done row by row.

```
data = [['', 0], [1, 10], [2, 15], [3, 14], [4, 15], [5, 14], ['', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'lastprice'])
df['new']=''
for i in range(1, len(df)-1):
    df.loc[i, 'new'] = df.loc[i, 'lastprice']*2 / (df.loc[i-1, 'lastprice'] + df.loc[i+1, 'lastprice'])
df.drop(df.index[df['new']==''], inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by='new', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

The top 3 values are in first 3 rows:

[image]